# Kubernetes v1.8.12 can't list *extensions.Deployment

Tags: kubernetes

everyone

Recently I upgraded my k8s cluster to v1.10.3, then I rolled it back to v1.9.8, then to v1.8.12. After that I found something I can't understand.

I can list deployment in my default namespace:

```
NAME                          DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
dunking-hedgehog-helmet       1         1         1            1           197d
kube-system-tomcat-official   1         1         1            1           197d
mongodb                       1         1         1            1           152d
smelly-pig-mysql              1         1         1            1           204d
```

But can't in my kube-system namespace:

```
# kubectl get deploy -nkube-system
Error from server: no kind "Deployment" is registered for version "apps/v1"
```

Also, the logs of apiserver startup:

```
E0530 10:47:09.511854       1 cacher.go:277] unexpected ListAndWatch error: storage/cacher.go:/daemonsets: Failed to list *extension
s.DaemonSet: no kind "DaemonSet" is registered for version "apps/v1"
E0530 10:47:09.534114       1 cacher.go:277] unexpected ListAndWatch error: storage/cacher.go:/daemonsets: Failed to list *extension
s.DaemonSet: no kind "DaemonSet" is registered for version "apps/v1"
E0530 10:47:09.577678       1 cacher.go:277] unexpected ListAndWatch error: storage/cacher.go:/replicasets: Failed to list *extensio
ns.ReplicaSet: no kind "ReplicaSet" is registered for version "apps/v1"
E0530 10:47:09.580008       1 cacher.go:277] unexpected ListAndWatch error: storage/cacher.go:/deployments: Failed to list *extensio
ns.Deployment: no kind "Deployment" is registered for version "apps/v1"
E0530 10:47:09.580234       1 cacher.go:277] unexpected ListAndWatch error: storage/cacher.go:/deployments: Failed to list *extensio
ns.Deployment: no kind "Deployment" is registered for version "apps/v1"
```

We all know API version apps/v1 is added since v1.9.0, so why does v1.8.12 try to register Deployment for version "apps/v1" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.10, objects in the apps API group began persisting in etcd in apps/v1 format (introduced in 1.9).

Rolling back to 1.9.x from 1.10.x is safe

If you want to roll back further to 1.8.x, you must first round trip all the apps/v1 resources (daemonsets, deployments, replicasets, statefulsets) to ensure they are persisted in etcd in a format that 1.8 can read.

The error you are getting indicates there is apps/v1 content in etcd which the kubernetes 1.8 apiserver cannot decode (since apps/v1 didn't exist in 1.8). The solution is to upgrade to 1.9.x, get/put all existing apps/v1 resources before downgrading to kube 1.8 again.

Comment: Thank you very much. So does 'round trip apps/v1 resources' mean reapply these resources with apps/v1beta2 api version? and by the way , after I upgrade to v1.10, do I need to reapply all resources under extensions/v1beta1 with apps/v1 api version ? or just leave the old resource no touch , and apply new resources with apps/v1 api version?

Comment: round trip meaning "get each object from the API then put it back to the API as is. Something like `kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces -o yaml | kubectl replace -f -`. 1.10 is able to read all old versions, so you can leave the resources as-is after upgrading and the next time they are written (whenever that is) the etcd stored version will be updated to apps/v1